# Cant convert String to double

Tags: java, string, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, double

So I got the latitude and longitude and successfully saved it on firebase, and now I was able to retrieve it and paste their values on a TextView.

I am planning to get the string value from the TextView and convert it to double and use that as a latitude and longitude to show a location on a map. I followed the format for converting string value to double value and it still wont work.

This is my code:

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
mMap = googleMap;

```
    String latitude = textViewLatt.getText().toString();
    String longitude = textViewLong.getText().toString();

    //Double latitude = Double.valueOf(textViewLatt.getText().toString());
    //Double longitude = Double.valueOf(textViewLong.getText().toString());

    double latt = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
    double longi= Double.parseDouble(longitude);

    //double latt = Double.valueOf(latitude);
    //double longi = Double.valueOf(longitude);

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latt, longi);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(sydney)
            .title("Marker"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
```

and these are the errors I got from debugging, I tried to search the problem and I couldnt find any solutions. Any help will be great.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PviBI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU9Ax.png)

Comment: Can you share an example value of the string that causes this error?

Comment: The error message clearly tells you that your code tries to convert the String "latitude" to a number, which will not work for obvious reasons. You need to debug why your String contains "latitude" instead of an actual number value.

Comment: I edited the post and put the latitude and longitude respectively, displayed on a textview

Comment: You should logging what's your textViewLatt.getText() return, it might return an object more than a a real string

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS so does my string value contains the word "latitude"? however it is shown on the textview as just number. but before I change the textview into the thos coordinates, the previous value of that textview was "latitude". does that value still exist even after I changed it to coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I found the problem, it seems like its getting the value even before I change the textview's value into numbers. thus it was trying to convert "latitude"(the previous value of the textview) to a double and instead of the coordinates.

Thank you for your suggestions guys!

Answer (score 0):

Check your text views, you are somehow failed to set the Digits of Lat Long values in TextViews properly and they contains alphabets thats why you are unable to parse them into Double.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).